# OSx : "No module named yamlog"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am absolutely new to python and tried to install Theano. 
Therefore I ran `$ pip install numpy scipy`.
Pip seems up to date but I always get the same error:

```
Collecting scripy
  Using cached Scripy-0.9.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/lk/v92bv9gs51x55nwp0cspt3xw0000gn/T/pip-build-ZdGtpP/scripy/setup.py", line 96, in <module>
        description=get_description(packages[0], PACKAGE_DIR),
      File "/private/var/folders/lk/v92bv9gs51x55nwp0cspt3xw0000gn/T/pip-build-ZdGtpP/scripy/setup.py", line 47, in get_description
        pkg = __import__(package, level=1)
      File "/private/var/folders/lk/v92bv9gs51x55nwp0cspt3xw0000gn/T/pip-build-ZdGtpP/scripy/lib/scripy/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .edit import *
      File "/private/var/folders/lk/v92bv9gs51x55nwp0cspt3xw0000gn/T/pip-build-ZdGtpP/scripy/lib/scripy/edit.py", line 18, in <module>
        import yamlog
    ImportError: No module named yamlog

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lk/v92bv9gs51x55nwp0cspt3xw0000gn/T/pip-build-ZdGtpP/scripy/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must have typed:

```
pip install numpy scripy    # <-- should be `scipy`
```

You can see clearly from the output it is attempting to install `scripy` not `scipy`.  Whatever this `scripy` pip package is, it clearly doesn't define its dependencies properly.

Comment: Damn, it sucks to to be dyslexic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify distribution and version but if you have python 2.7 I guess this might work.

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git
sudo pip install Theano
```